# EF Core dynamic filtered include

Tags: ef-core-5.0

In EF Core we can eager load related data with `.Include()`.

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Include(blog => blog.Posts);
```

We can also use its dynamic overloaded [`Include()`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/231565fb03ea76fbb9b7f7a5744a4246e4641e74/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2453-L2469) by passing in a string

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Include("Posts");
```

EF Core 5.0 has introduced [filtered include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) where you could filter related data:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Include(blog => blog.Posts.Where(post => post.Title == "Hello World"));
```

How do I get the filtered include working with the dynamic overloaded version?

I have a non-generic `IQueryable` which I have to call `Include()` on using reflection. It's easier to invoke the method that accepts a `string` than the other one that accepts a `Expression<Func<Blog, IEnumerable<Post>>>`.

Comment: Short answer: not possible. But what's the problem with adding typed Includes conditionally? Is is such a bad thing to have a couple of `if` statements?

Comment: Because I'm using the non-generic `IQueryable`. It doesn't have `Include()` as a method or extension method. Only the generic `IQueryable<TEntity>` has. `TEntity` is not known during compile time, hence the non-generic version. That is why `Include()` has to be invoked using reflection. It's easier to invoke the non-typed `Include()` than the typed one.

Comment: I really wonder where that takes you. Even if you want to Include anything without filtering you have to scope out the queried type to know which properties can be included. IMO you may as well start with a typed queryable by getting the type one step earlier in the code.

Comment: We have fifty `TEntity` inheriting from a common class using EF Core Table per Type (TPT). It's a design choice so that we could extend an entity independantly in the future. So these fifty tables have the same set of columns. The client (web browser) will send to the server which `TEntity` it's interested in, therefore the type couldn't be determined during compile time. We're reluctant to have a switch-case with fifty ugly cases, hence the reflection approach.